# How to add validation to dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select, dropdown

I would like to add some simple validation to my drop downs. For example there are 3 dropdowns alongside each other containing data. I would to allow to select one item from each dropdown at the time. Once the user has selected the data the dropdown should be disabled so it stops the user from choosing another item within that same dropdown. I have attempted it but was not successful,

```js
my_condition = true;
var lastSel = $("#column1 option:selected");

$("#column1").change(function() {
  if (my_condition) {
    lastSel.attr("selected", true);
  }
});

$("#column1").click(function() {
  lastSel = $("#column1 option:selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="column1" class="text_select" name="column1" onChange="">
  <option value="">- Preferred Time -</option>
  <option value="- Sold Out -">- Sold Out -</option>
  <option value="2:30 - 4:00pm">2:30 - 4:00pm</option>
</select>
<select id="column2" class="text_select" name="column2" onChange="">
  <option value="">- Preferred Time -</option>
  <option value="- Sold Out -">- Sold Out -</option>
  <option value="2:30 - 4:00pm">2:30 - 4:00pm</option>
</select>

<select id="column3" class="text_select" name="column3" onChange="">
  <option value="">- Preferred Time -</option>
  <option value="- Sold Out -">- Sold Out -</option>
  <option value="2:30 - 4:00pm">2:30 - 4:00pm</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code HERE. The "post code if you post a link to a fiddle" is there for a reason! I created a snippet for you using the `<>` button in the editor

Comment: @mplungjan thnak you for editing my post i struggled to do it that way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add disable validation to a dropdown after it has been selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934208/how-to-add-disable-validation-to-a-dropdown-after-it-has-been-selected)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a function that disables the element

```
function onChange(elem) {
    $(elem).prop("disabled",true);
}
```

Use `prop()` for boolean attributes (those which don't have a value), like `disabled` or `readonly`.

And then, use the function as the `onchange` handler of each select, passing `this` as the first param. `this` will be the select which is being changed.

```
<select id="column1" class="text_select" name="column1" onchange="onChange(this);">
```

---

Or, simpler, assign the event handler from jQuery:

```
$("#column1,#column2,#column3").on("change",function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled",true);
});
```